# web.xml for jersey servlets not responding to the request

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, jersey

Hi i tried to create a REST web service using jersey 1.8 . i run as run on server. and server started successfully. but the requests not get in to the service class. browser shows 404 error. my web.xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MavenSample</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name> 
          <param-value>java.com.mine.rest.HelloWorldServices</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

and my rest service class is

```
package com.mine.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("service")
public class HelloWorldServices {

     @GET
     @Path("hello")
      @Produces("text/html")
      public Response getLocalCust() {

               String output = "Hello marvel , welcome to Rest Web service ";
               return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
      }



}
```

my pom.xml is

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MavenSample</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenSample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

          <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8</version>
                </dependency>
          </dependencies>

</project>
```

Please help me to overcome this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.com.mine.rest.HelloWorldServices` isn't a package. The property value int the web.xml should be `com.mine.rest`.

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name> 
  <param-value>com.mine.rest</param-value>
</init-param>
```

This will scan all classes in the `com.mine.rest` package and its sub-packages for all your resource classes annotated with `@Path`

Comment: Hai, thanks for ur support. i changed my web.xml to  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name> 
          <param-value>com.mine.rest</param-value> but still the problem is alive...

Comment: If you don't set the `<finalName>` in the `<build>` it's possible your war is getting built with the version suffix `MavenSample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. So the version should be part of the url. Try adding `<finalName>${project.artifactId}<finalName>` inside the `<build>` in your pom

Comment: Hi, i am using maven version 3.3.3 . is there any problem with that?

Comment: Shouldn't be. Did you make the fix I said to?

Comment: yes , i did it. but still the issue is occuring :-(

Comment: Look in your server. Make sure the war name is `MavenSample`. Then look inside the exploded war in the `WEB-INF/lib` to make sure all your jars are exported with the app

Comment: Also what IDE are you using? Maybe I can point in the direction to get a simple startup app working.

Comment: i am using eclipse Kepler

Comment: Thank you sir, thanks a lot. it helps me. i use the remote archetype to create the project.